# Cannot get User.Name from HttpContext in .net core. DI does not solve it

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, httpcontext

I need to get the current ApplicationUser info into my context (inherited from IdentityDbContext. For that purpose I have created a UserResolverService, as explained by [Rion Williams](http://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/). I have registered both `IHttpContextAccessor` and `UserResolverServices` in Startup. But even in the Service, the User remains null, even though the user is positively logged in. what am I missing?

I have created a simple environment looking like this:

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private string _userName;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, UserResolverService userService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _userName = userService.GetActualUser();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

My UserResolverService

```
public class UserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public string GetActualUser()
    {
        if(_accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            return _accessor.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
        }
        var dummy = "Dummy";
        return dummy;
        //
    }
}
```

My ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<UserResolverService>();

        services.AddMvc();

    }
```

Comment: You've neglected to show the most important part: where and how you're utilizing your context, when the user is null.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I do not understand your comment. I am deploying a generic VS2017 template with Identity (Individual Accounts). When LoggedIn, I want to retrieve the TenantId from the User for further processing. I have a solution for that, but that requires getting the Name from the current user. All the instructions tell me to create a service and use HttpContextAccessor for that purpose. fyi, I am using .net core 2.0.